# How to set sticky variables in VB6

Tags: vb6

I am brand new to Visual Basic 6 and have no chance of upgrading to a newer platform. We need to make a couple changes to an existing program.

I have a form (Form1) with 3 textboxes. I need to save each textbox value after the user fills them in.

After the user presses the Enter key, the value for that box should be saved and later tested for empty values from a single function/Sub.

Here is what I have so far:

```
Private Sub empId_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
  If KeyCode = 13 Then
    Dim empId As String
    empId = Form1.empId.Text 'Save this for a later test
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub orderNo_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
  If KeyCode = 13 Then
    Dim orderNo As String
    orderNo = Form1.orderNo.Text 'Save this for a later test
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub partNo_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
  If KeyCode = 13 Then
    Dim partNo As String
    partNo = Form1.partNo.Text 'Save this for a later test
  End If
End Sub
```

After all the variables have been set, I would like to do something similar to:

```
if(!empId || !orderNo || !partNo) {
  // show error
} else{
  // process the data
}
```

Can someone show me how this should be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code is similar to what you already have provided, but should do what you need:

```
Option Explicit

Private m_empID As String
Private m_orderNo As String
Private m_partNo As String

Private Sub Form_Load()
   Me.KeyPreview = True
End Sub

Private Sub Form_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
   m_empID = empID.Text
   m_orderNo = orderNo.Text
   m_partNo = partNo.Text
End Sub

Private Sub ASubCalledLater()
   If m_empID = "" Or m_orderNo = "" Or m_partNo = "" Then
      ' show error
   Else
      ' process the data
   End If
End Sub
```

You will need to set `KeyPreview` for the form to True for this to work.

Comment: Thank you Brian, this is very helpful. So, once the vars are set in the private Subs, they are available outside of their scope?

Comment: Yes, because they are declared at the form level.

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance, but I'm using a form and not a module. And, regarding the KeyPreview, would I be correct to set that as: `this.KeyPreview = true;` from within the ASubCalledLater Sub?

Comment: You could set `KeyPreview` through the Form Designer or as I did in the modified code.  Also, I meant to say form and not module.

Comment: Thank you Brian!!

Comment: Although this article is for VBA, the concepts apply to VB6: [Scope of variables in Visual Basic for Applications](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/141693/scope-of-variables-in-visual-basic-for-applications)

Comment: @ÉtienneLaneville, Thank you for that resource!! Very helpful information.

Comment: Note that @BrianMStafford has also renamed the variables so that they are different that the form controls.  Without doing this, you'll get one of two effects, depending upon where the variables are defined:  If they're defined at the form level of the form, you'll get a compilation error because of the name collision.  If they're defined in another module, they will be masked (unavailable) because of the scope rules of VB6; this can be gotten around by fully specifying the variable (eg. Module1.Text1), but will lead to confusing and unclear code.

Comment: Also, in addition to using KeyPreview to process the Enter key, I also like to use the .LostFocus event to do the same action (save the textbox contents to the variable).  I find that this makes usage of the system more intuitive to the user, since the contents of the textboxes are always the same as the internal variables (which is not the case in the above code if the Enter key isn't pressed).  In fact, to me, the biggest benefit of capturing the Enter key is preventing the annoying "ding" whenever it's pressed otherwise...